# Pytest mocking: pass kwargs through side_effect function

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I want to test a file called **ninja.py** wrote in Python3.6.

```py
# File ninja.py

def what_to_do_result(result):
    # Send a mail, write something in a file, play a song or whatever


def my_function(a, b):
    # Step 1
    result = a + b

    # Step 2
    if result == 3:
        what_to_do_result(result)
    elif result == 5:
        what_to_do_result(result + 1)
    else:
        return True
```

I have started writing a test file called **test_ninjapy** and wrote some unittest. I do use Pytest.

```py
import pytest

class MyTestException(Exception):
    pass


def run_side_effect(*args, **kwargs):
    raise MyTestException(kwargs["result"])


@pytest.fixture(name="resource")
def setup_fixture():
    # Some code here

class TestNinja:
    @staticmethod
    def setup_method():
        # Function called before each test

    @staticmethod
    def teardown_method():
        # Function called after each test

    @staticmethod
    def test_my_function(mocker, resource):
        # How to do this ???
        mocker.patch("ninja.what_to_do_result", return_value=None, side_effect=run_side_effect)

        # Then the test
        assert 1 == 1 # -> This works
        with pytest.raises(MyTestException):
            ninja_function(a=1, b=2)
        assert ninja_function(a=5, b=10)
```

The point is that I want to mock the function **ninja.what_to_do_result** and apply a *side effect* (= run a function).
I want the side effect to **use the parameter (kwargs) or the function what_to_do_result**.
But I don't know how to do this.

For example:

Because there are multiple possibilities (in the step 2, the call of *what_to_do_result* could be with **3 & 5**, which are linked with 2 differents use cases I wxant to test.

Can you help me?

I did not found the related section in the documentation below.

Link to the documentation: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock

Comment: if you call the function like this: `what_to_do_result(result)` then `kwargs` in the side effect func will be empty, because you passed `result` as a positional arg. (i.e. it will arrive as `args[0]` instead).

Comment: you could define your side effect func to have the same signature as the target function i.e. `def run_side_effect(result):` and then however you call it the value will arrive as `result` arg in the side effect func

Comment: or if you want a generic side effect func using args and kwargs, and you want the value to come in as `kwargs['result']` then you have to call the func that way: `what_to_do_result(result=result)` and `what_to_do_result(result=result + 1)`

Comment: see https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/

Comment: Nice, thank you for your answer mate. I do have followed the first method. :) 
I will probably answer this question (if you do not) if you do not, to help people to find the solution